# Unity - Refresh .asset after Destroying a Subasset

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-editor

So some context:
I'm currently working on an EditorWindow in Unity to make a custom Rule System. This Rule System is composed of a bunch of classes all deriving from ScriptableObject, so I can create Instances of them and still access them in that one window. (took me forever to get this to work, since I started without ScriptableObjects)
The Asset that holds the whole Rule System is called Ruleset and itself is a ScriptableObject too. I basicly just replaced the Inspector of the Ruleset ScriptableObject to give me a Button to open the EditorWindow where I then can edit the whole Ruleset at once.
To organize the whole thing, I'm doing this to create a new Rule in that Ruleset:

```cs
Rule newRule = CreateInstance<Rule>();
// currentRuleset is the SerializedObject of the Ruleset, so it's targetObject is the ruleset ScriptableObject
AssetDatabase.AddObjectToAsset(newRule, currentRuleset.targetObject);
// Reimport the new Asset so it shows up in the UnityEditor
AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(newRule));
```

This part works great. All Rules show up as Sub-Assets of the Ruleset-ScriptableObject. I then add it to a list in the Ruleset and apply the modified properties, so it all gets saved.

Now to my problem:
When I want to remove a Rule from that Ruleset, the only ways to achieve that I've found are removing the object from the Asset and destroying it, so I do the following:

```cs
// ruleList is the SerializedProperty of a List<Rule> in the ruleset, so accessing values inside it is a bit fidilly
// Remove the last rule SubAsset from the ruleset mainAsset
AssetDatabase.RemoveObjectFromAsset(ruleList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(ruleList.arraySize - 1).objectReferenceValue);
// Destroy the rule ScriptableObject so it is actually deleted
DestroyImmediate(ruleList.GetArrayElementAtIndex(ruleList.arraySize - 1).objectReferenceValue, true);
currentRuleset.ApplyModifiedProperties(); // <- currentRuleset is the SerializedObject of the ruleset
// Reimport the mainAsset so the changes show up in the UnityEditor
AssetDatabase.ImportAsset(AssetDatabase.GetAssetPath(currentRuleset.targetObject));
```

This also works, BUT, Unity throws me a Warning each time I remove a Rule from the Ruleset because of the ImportAsset-Command:

> Importer(NativeFormatImporter) generated inconsistent result for asset(guid:e23e75a89de672045aeaa42eeb54b26e)

Is there any better way to do this? If I remove the import command, changes will not show up in Unity until I reimport or compile again. (I also recieve this warning when I manually reimport the asset)

Comment: Try using [AssetDatabase.Refresh](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetDatabase.Refresh.html) after removing the rule instead of ImportAsset.   "This will import any assets that have changed their content modification data or have been added-removed to the project folder."

Comment: @hijinxbassist I did try that, forgot to mention it though, but tried it again just to be sure. Sadly when I use AssetDatabase.Refresh it doesn't do anything. So yes there is no warning, but also it doesn't update the Asset in the Project Window :(

Answer (score 0):

Using:

```
AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
```

actually updates the parent asset (and all other unsaved assets in the project) with the proper remaining sub-assets. It does not (at least with my setup) trigger the inconsistency error that *AssetDatabase.ImportAsset()* seems to trigger.

There is also

```
AssetDatabase.SaveAssetIfDirty(parentObject);
```

I did not manage to get a consistent result with this approach and often needed a reimport of the object (which then sometimes triggered the inconsistency warning).

For reference in case someone runs into the same issue: from what I have observed, once the inconsistency warning shows up on an object, any code or manual editor reimport of that particular object triggers it again each time. The only way I found to solve it definitely was to clear out all sub-assets for the main asset, by looping over the list that *AssetDatabase.LoadAllAssetRepresentationsAtPath()* returns.